# Multilingual web-page using subdirectories within a single domain

Tags: multilingual, subdirectory

I want my webpage to be in multiple languages on the same domain, for example:

domain.com/en

domain.com/ru

I can manually translate `index.html` into the languages I need, this is not a problem.
I tried to google the solution for hours, in the end I came across only theory. Like what is better: sub-domain or sub-directory. I haven't found any guides on how to implement this. I understand that domain.com/your_language is just folder containing your web-page stuff in a specific language, but I'm pretty sure there is more to set up or adjust for this.

My hosting provider is using apache on a linux machine. Personally, I only have access to the `public_html folder`.

[image]

Personally, I don't care about search engine rankings, because this is my diploma project and I may not publish it in the end.

Would really appreciate it if someone guided me to the right place to get started.

Thank you!

Comment: It's really that simple, you just create a subdirectory for `/en` and one for `/ru` in your `public_html` directory, and place the corresponding translations in those, as detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/managing-multi-regional-sites#using-locale-specific-urls) by Google. If you want Google to index them, and they're not already linked to somewhere else that's indexed, you can create a sitemap with `<loc>` to specify the targeted language, as covered [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions#sitemap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this with .htaccess configuration in root directory thanks to: https://gist.github.com/markhowellsmead/0c414cea619727a3618b

```
RewriteEngine On

#English
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /en/ [L,R=301]

#Estonian
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^et [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /ee/ [L,R=301]

#Russian
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^ru [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /ru/ [L,R=301]
```

What my `public_html` folder looks like now:

[image]

Comment: You should leave your index.html file in place for user agents that don't send `Accept-Language` (mostly bots) or send one that isn't one you support.   It should have links to your various languages so that users can choose.

Comment: I think that I will redirect everyone else to /en/ folder. That'll do for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons why your page will not be indexed by Google.

If there are no restrictions for indexing, In general, they act as follows:

First, verify ownership of your site.  This can be done in various ways https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9008080?hl=en

Then tell Google that there are pages on your site that can be indexed.  This can also be done in various ways.  Here are the fastest:

- for online pages
  Indexing API
  https://developers.google.com/search/apis/indexing-api/v3/quickstart?hl=ru
- for offline pages
  https://web.dev/content-indexing-api/